# Apache Camel Mail component: No component found with scheme: smtp

Tags: java, spring, maven, email, apache-camel

I'm trying to use The Apache Camel SMTP component in my simple Spring application, but there is an exception :

```
because of Failed to resolve endpoint: smtp://smtp.gmail.com?password=pwd&username=username due to: No component found with scheme: smtp
```

Her is my route code snippet (the other routes are working as well ) :

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("jmsComponent:queue:" + appProperties.getJmsPathFromAppRemoteService())
                        .to("bean:remoteService?method=sendEcho");

                from("direct:sendEmail")
                        .to("smtp://smtp.gmail.com?username=username&password=pwd");
            }
        });
```

And I put this maven dependency to my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Could anyone help me ? What do I need to do ?

Comment: an exception? Please tell more. Give further details and what did you investigate at your own to avoid obvious answers.

Comment: Normally adding maven dependency (camel-mail) is enough. However if you still get the exception, please check your deploy process.